# Yahoo Stock Feed

Tags: php, web-scraping, yahoo, yahoo-finance, stock

I'm trying to get a chart of stock opening prices.

I want to use yahoo's data feed for stock data: http://www.gummy-stuff.org/Yahoo-data.htm

Has anyone ever used this? What I want is basically a 1 column table, each row represents one day, and the first column represents the opening price of a particular stock.

How can I query more than just one day?

Comment: I'm confused by your proposed data model.  You want a "1 column table" with the "first column" representing the opening price.  How do you know **what stock** the price is for?  How do you know the date?

Comment: its besides the point. what stock it is is not the idea. the idea is, i want to input a start date and end date, and then get a list of multiple days.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how you could retrieve data and parse it:

```
$sourceURL = 'http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=AAPL&f=snd1lyr';

$sourceData  = file_get_contents( $sourceURL );

// separate into lines
$sourceLines = str_getcsv($sourceData, "\n"); 

foreach( $sourceLines as $line ) {

    $contents = str_getcsv( $line );

    // Now, is an array of the comma-separated contents of a line
}
```

**Update:**

Yahoo provides historial data e.g. for AAPL on this page:

```
http://de.finance.yahoo.com/q/hp?s=AAPL
```

At the bottom of the page, you may download the table using this link:

```
http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=AAPL&d=3&e=22&f=2011&g=d&a=8&b=7&c=1984&ignore=.csv
```

I'd propose to play with the webpage to learn which parameters represent what.

Comment: I've added a link for provides multi-day data.

Comment: I have a blog post that breaks down the parameters. So much more then just quotes you can get, can get dividends, bid, ask, moving averages etc all from Yahoo. http://www.jarloo.com/yahoo_finance/

Answer (score 2):

List of parameters according to [gummystuff](http://www.gummy-stuff.org/Yahoo-data.htm) :

a    Ask
a2   Average Daily Volume
a5   Ask Size
b    Bid
b2   Ask (Real-time)
b3   Bid (Real-time)
b4   Book Value
b6   Bid Size
c    Change & Percent Change
c1   Change
c3   Commission
c6   Change (Real-time)
c8   After Hours Change (Real-time)
d    Dividend/Share
d1   Last Trade Date
d2   Trade Date
e    Earnings/Share
e1   Error Indication (returned for symbol changed / invalid)
e7   EPS Estimate Current Year
e8   EPS Estimate Next Year
e9   EPS Estimate Next Quarter
f6   Float Shares
g    Day's Low
h    Day's High
j    52-week Low
k    52-week High
g1   Holdings Gain Percent
g3   Annualized Gain
g4   Holdings Gain
g5   Holdings Gain Percent (Real-time)
g6   Holdings Gain (Real-time)
i    More Info
i5   Order Book (Real-time)
j1   Market Capitalization
j3   Market Cap (Real-time)
j4   EBITDA
j5   Change From 52-week Low
j6   Percent Change From 52-week Low
k1   Last Trade (Real-time) With Time
k2   Change Percent (Real-time)
k3   Last Trade Size
k4   Change From 52-week High
k5   Percebt Change From 52-week High
l    Last Trade (With Time)
l1   Last Trade (Price Only)
l2   High Limit
l3   Low Limit
m    Day's Range
m2   Day's Range (Real-time)
m3   50-day Moving Average
m4   200-day Moving Average
m5   Change From 200-day Moving Average
m6   Percent Change From 200-day Moving Average
m7   Change From 50-day Moving Average
m8   Percent Change From 50-day Moving Average
n    Name
n4   Notes
o    Open
p    Previous Close
p1   Price Paid
p2   Change in Percent
p5   Price/Sales
p6   Price/Book
q    Ex-Dividend Date
r    P/E Ratio
r1   Dividend Pay Date
r2   P/E Ratio (Real-time)
r5   PEG Ratio
r6   Price/EPS Estimate Current Year
r7   Price/EPS Estimate Next Year
s    Symbol
s1   Shares Owned
s7   Short Ratio
t1   Last Trade Time
t6   Trade Links
t7   Ticker Trend
t8   1 yr Target Price
v    Volume
v1   Holdings Value
v7   Holdings Value (Real-time)
w    52-week Range
w1   Day's Value Change
w4   Day's Value Change (Real-time)
x    Stock Exchange
y    Dividend Yield

Comment: This list is incomplete. I have a listing on my blog is anyone is interested http://www.jarloo.com/yahoo_finance/